# jQuery loop through divs and display text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following structure below. Using jQuery I need to take each link and display the href below it. I can use some child selectors to write code for each but I simply want to write something that does it for all div's with the 'col' class, and will allow for future additions...

```
<div class="col">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <a href="http://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
</div>
```

The above should turn into...

```
<div class="col">
    <a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
    <span>http://google.com</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <a href="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo!</a>
    <span>http://yahoo.com</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <a href="http://facebook.com">Facebook</a>
    <span>http://facebook.com</span>
</div>

<div class="col">
    <a href="http://twitter.com">Twitter</a>
    <span>http://twitter.com</span>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Don't even know where to begin..If I store '.col a'  href into a variable, it will be overwritten by each..haven't done something like this in a while

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This smacks of you not having tried to write the code at all. You should really be able to do this on your own.

```
$('.col a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("<span>"+$this.attr('href')+"</span>").insertAfter($this);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('div.col').each(function(){
  alert($(this).find("a").attr("href"));
  //figure out the rest yourself
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.col > a').after(function() { 
    return $('<span>', {text:this.href});
});
```

Comment: Very simplified solution, I like it.

Answer (score 0):

this should do it. you can use each. read more about selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div.col").each(function(){
      var hreftext = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
      $(this).append("<span>" + hreftext + "</span>");
   });
```

});
​

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

```
$('div.col').each(function() {
    var $a = $(this).find('a:first'),
        href = $a.attr('href');
    $('<span>').text(href).insertAfter($a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".col").each(function(){
 var v= $(this).find("a");       
 $("<span/>",{text:v.attr('href')}).insertAfter(v);
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C8Zd7/4/)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a basic jQuery 'append()'

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vRB2D/)

```
$('div.col').each(function(){
        var href = $(this).children('a:first').attr('href');
        $(this).append('<span>' + href + '</span>');
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

yes I agree with each solution. But it would be better if you cache your selector.<strike>Otherwise each time jQuery has to dive into DOM.</strike> If its a big list may affect performance.

```
var col = $('.col a');
col.each(function(){
  var val = $(this).text();
  $(this).append("<span>"+val);
})​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cXkqc/2/

**Update**

There was a mistake from my part to interpreting the question. Updated code & link.

```
 var col = $('.col a');
   col.each(function(){
   var val = $(this).attr('href');
   $(this).after("<span>"+val);
 })​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cXkqc/3/

thanks @am not i am

Comment: *"Otherwise each time jQuery has to dive into DOM..."* That's not right. That's only the case if you're going to reuse the `.col a` selection. If you're only using it once, then jQuery will only do one DOM selection.

Comment: oh sorry.. that sentence was a mistake. Please read it  -  "But it would be better to cache your selector, if you are planning to use it somewhere else". thanks - @amnotiam

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but your answer doesn't do what the question asked. I don't know why yours was accepted.

Comment: interesting!! masedesign shows what should be the output and my code does that only. Why people down voting without telling the reason. Its nothing to do with points. But this is a place to help, share & learn code. If down voting pls tell the reason so that we can improve or rectify mistakes.

Comment: Your code does not do that. If you tested it, you would see that the output is entirely different.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8453/discussion-between-praveen-vijayan-and-am-not-i-am)

Comment: please do not give negative points with out mentioning the reason.